# Dividing twice by N faster than dividing by N^2?

Tags: c++, optimization, division, divide

Can anyone answer why this statement:

```
unsigned int index; 
unsigned int i;  
unsigned int n;  
while (condition) {
    i = index / n / n;
}
```

Is faster than:

```
unsigned int index; 
unsigned int i;  
unsigned int n;  
unsigned int n2 = n * n;  

while (condition) {
    i = index / n2;
}
```

Very strange, here is the video of me demonstrating it: [removed]

The statement gets ran 400,000 times or and ends up being 0.15 seconds slower. I am cleaning my .o files and remaking with -O3 optimization each time I run the test. Using gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 on Red Hat 4.4.7-4

Update:

As suggested I converted it to assembly to check it out. My limited knowledge of assembly doesn't reveal answers though, in fact it seems the faster solution should take longer because more operations

```
 128:utils.cpp     ****         i = index / farm_size / farm_size;
 1221                   .loc 8 129 0
 1222 046a 8B459C           movl    -100(%rbp), %eax
 1223 046d BA000000         movl    $0, %edx
 1223      00
 1224 0472 F7B57CFF         divl    -132(%rbp)
 1224      FFFF
GAS LISTING /tmp/cc4vphk8.s             page 44
 1225 0478 BA000000         movl    $0, %edx
 1225      00
 1226 047d F7B57CFF         divl    -132(%rbp)
 1226      FFFF
 1227 0483 8945B8           movl    %eax, -72(%rbp)
 129:utils.cpp     ****         j = (index / farm_size) % farm_size;
```

.

```
 128:utils.cpp     ****         i = index / farm_area;
 1221                   .loc 8 129 0
 1222 046a 8B459C           movl    -100(%rbp), %eax
 1223 046d BA000000         movl    $0, %edx
 1223      00
 1224 0472 F775D8           divl    -40(%rbp)
 1225 0475 8945B8           movl    %eax, -72(%rbp)
GAS LISTING /tmp/ccNU8jKx.s             page 44
 129:utils.cpp     ****         j = (index / farm_size) % farm_size;
```

here is a side by side comparsion:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yXvN.png

Comment: Impossible to tell when we don't know `condition` or what the values of `index`, `i` or `n` are and that the video is private.

Comment: Since the difference is so minuscule I am forced to assume that the difference comes from that first multiplication `n * n` and the time it takes to move around that value in memory.

Comment: Generate the assembly listing for your app and inspect it.  No need for a video...

Comment: What is condition? Does it involve a calculation with `i`?

Comment: @Abhinav Are you on drugs?

Comment: This cannot be answered until we at least see realistic code.

Comment: @Abhinav: Changing `index / (n squared)` into `index / (2 n)` was a rather unexpected suggestion.

Comment: Ahh I see my bad, I used `i = index / n2` and that looked like `n* 2`, response deleted :P That lunch lady never liked me anyways.. :D

Comment: Added assembly but can't make heads or tails

Comment: Was taking the easy way and pasting the disassembled code into your question too efficient?

Comment: How could I do a side by side comparison of the two in just text alone? I guess ill paste them anyways

Comment: Nice work ignoring compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is important information in your video that you did not put in the code.

The double-division code which runs in 1.15s is shown here

[image]

The single-division code which runs in 1.34s is shown here:
[image]

One important difference which is not evident in the posted question is the set of variables that are in your loop.

In the faster code, you have `i`, `j`, `k`, `index`, `farm_size`.

In the slower code, you have `i`, `j`, `k`, `index`, `farm_size`, **and** `farm_area`.

So even though you're doing one less division, you're moving around more variables which is what is costing you the extra time.

Comment: So a reduction of 400,000 less divisions in this case isn't better because the code needs access to `farm_size` anyways?

Comment: Yes moving data between registers and RAM is slower than arithmetic that is already loaded into the registers.

Comment: also, note that a good compiler can be smart enough to reduce the /n/n case into one less operation.  for example: i=index/farm_size; j=i%farm_size; k=index%farm_size; i=i/farm_size;  so total # of division is the same in the /n/n vs /n2, but /n/n has fewer memory variables to access.

Comment: note also that in intel a divl gives you both the result and the remainder in a single shot, so  i=index/farm_size; k=index%farm_size; is actually a single instruction.  so basically, a really smart compiler would translate the code (in the /n/n case) i=index/farm_size; j=i%farm_size; k=index%farm_size; i=i/farm_size; into 2 divl instructions.  The first does i=index/farm_size and  k=index%farm_size, and the second does j=i%farm_size and i=i/farm_size.  In the /n2 scenario, it is more difficult for the compiler to back trace farm_area and figure all of this out.